# FireBase FIRMessagingSecureSocket crashing iOS app

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have built an app where people can send messages to other users.  My server then makes requests to Firebase to send a notification to the receiving user's device.  During internal testing, it works fine.  But now that we have open beta testers, there is an error that shows up in Crashlytics for:

- UIApplicationMain
- signalEventSync
- [FIRMessagingSecureSocket stream:handleEvent:]
- [FIRMessagingSecureSocket performRead]
- [NSData(NSData) subdataWithRange:]
- Fatal Exception: NSRangeException
  *** -[NSConcreteMutableData subdataWithRange:]: range {0, 18446744073709551423} exceeds data length 16384

Crashyltics logs it about 3-5 times an hour for iOS 10.0.2, 10.0.3, and 10.1.0.  So it appears only a small minority is problematic. I've been logging the requests my server makes to Firebase and none of the payloads (JSON, only text) are exceeding a couple hundred characters.  I'm using FireBaseCore 3.4.3 and developing with XCode 8.0, Swift 3.0.  I have the same app for Android and there are no logs of this crash happening.

Emails I have had with FireBase support have not given any insights to this issue.  Has anyone had an issue similar to this?  Or any ideas of where to look next?